# Java: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

```
import java.io.*;

public class tempdetection {
public static int celciustofarenheit(int temp){
    int fTemp = ((9 * temp)/5) + 32;
    return fTemp;
}


public static void examineTemperature(int temp){
    System.out.println("\nTemperature is " + temp + " in celcius. Hmmm...");

    int fTemp = celciustofarenheit(temp);
    System.out.println("\nThats " + fTemp + " in Farenheit...");

    if(fTemp<20)
        System.out.println("\n***Burrrr. Its cold...***\n\n");
    else if(fTemp>20 || fTemp<50)
        System.out.println("\n***The weather is niether too hot nor too cold***\n\n");
    else if(fTemp>50)
        System.out.println("\n***Holy cow.. Its scorching.. Too hot***\n\n");
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int temperature;
    char c;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    do{
        System.out.println("Input:\n(Consider the input is from the sensor)\n");

        temperature = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        examineTemperature(temperature);
        System.out.println("Does the sensor wanna continue giving input?:(y/n)\n");
        c = (char) br.read();
    }while(c!= 'N' && c!='n');          //if c==N that is no then stop



}

}
```

This is the complete code guys.. I still din get my answer.. I've searched a lot on net but to no avail.. Also thanks for who've already helped but that din resolve my problem.. Temperature is int.. SO why i should convert to string.??
Also i tried try catch as specified by one of the member but then examineTemperature(temperature) throws n error saying its not initialized..

```
Input:
(Consider the input is from the sensor)

45

Temperature is 45 in celcius. Hmmm...

Thats 113 in Farenheit...

***The weather is niether too hot nor too cold***


Does the sensor wanna continue giving input?:(y/n)

N
Input:
(Consider the input is from the sensor)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at tempdetection.main(tempdetection.java:33)
```

Also it works fyn until it reaches while loop..

Comment: Try `c = (char) br.readLine();`

Comment: @RongNK: nope, the error's actually here: `c!= 'N' || c!='n'`. That `||` should be an `&&`.

Comment: I changed but to no avail.. @Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the line

```
temperature = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

This is reading in the input and trying to parse it as an Integer. As the exception suggests the input is not a number i.e. `NumberFormatException` as `Integer.parseInt()` expects the argument to be a number.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

One way (I personally believe not the best) is to catch the exception and just do nothing and continue

```
try
{
    temperature = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    // and do any code that uses temperature
    //if you don't then temperature will not be assigned
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfex)
{}
```

A better way would be to check the input string is a number before trying to parse

```
String input = br.readLine();
if(input.matches("\\d+"))  // Only ints so don't actually need to consider decimals
    //is a number... do relevant code
    temperature = Integer.parseInt(input);
else
    //not a number
    System.out.println("Not a number that was input");
```

Comment: Try and catch gives an error saying temperature not initialized.. Though temperature is getting a input from user.. And the second method i din understand since why should i convert it to string since the value that i wanna pass is a int.. I've sent the whole code.. U can examine.. @Java Devil

Comment: Yes, if it fails to parse the input then temperature will not have been initialised. See my edit. And I was saying to read in the String so that you could match it with a regex. Really the main problem you are having is you are trying to create a number from a letter when you input 'N'

Comment: Hey it worked!! Thanks alot.. I used try catch to resolve it thank u!!

Answer (score 4):

In your do/while loop's condition, the `||` should be an `&&`:

```
do{
    System.out.println("Input:\n(Consider the input is from the sensor)\n");
    temperature = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    examineTemperature(temperature);
    System.out.println("Does the sensor wanna continue giving input?:(y/n)\n");
    c = (char) br.read();
} while (c != 'N' && c != 'n');
```

Comment: I dont think so thats the actual problem @Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse a string that can't convert to a integer number.

Integer.parseInt(String s) throw this exception;

Comment: I will improve, @RongNK

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen **Number format exception** like this:

```
     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
     java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
     com.tejveer.hiandroiddevelopers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
```

this type of error is created then application will be crashed.

then resolved this problem by writing the separate method

like this

```
public void thisIsMethod(View textView){
    EditText edtFn = findViewById(R.id.efn);
    EditText edtSN = findViewById(R.id.esn);
     int mResult = Integer.parseInt(edtFn.getText().toString())*
     Integer.parseInt(edtSN.getText().toString());
}
```

This method write outside this block

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  }
```